# I'm not sure how to break out of a loop when I finish sorting linked list

Tags: java, sorting, loops, linked-list

So what I am trying to do is to sort linked list. I'm stuck on breaking out of the loop where it seems that it never escapes. From examples I found all I had to do is to check if next value would be null, so what am I doing wrong?

Also, since I can't figure out why this won't brake out of loop, does this code seems like should do linked list sorting correctly?

```
    public void sortFirst() { 
        do
        {
            if (first.iData >= first.next.iData)
            {
                int iTempData = first.iData;
                double dTempData = first.dData;

                first.iData = first.next.iData;
                first.dData = first.next.dData;

                Link newLink = new Link(iTempData, dTempData);
                newLink.next = first;
                first = newLink;
            }
        }
        while (first.next != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, right off the bat, you have a logic problem in your last 3 lines:

```
            Link newLink = new Link(iTempData, dTempData);
            newLink.next = first;
            first = newLink;
```

Here, you set newLink.next = first.  Therefore it isn't null.  Next you set first = newLink.  So you can quickly see that first.next will never be null.

From what I can tell in your loop, you are not actually shifting nodes around in your list, 
but only data within the nodes.  In which case, you only need to move the data around:

```
            int iTempData = first.iData;
            double dTempData = first.dData;

            first.iData = first.next.iData;
            first.dData = first.next.dData;

            first.next.iData = iTempData;
            first.next.dData = dTempData;
```

(and remove the last 3 lines which create the new node and insert it incorrectly in the list). 
Of course, that is a little ugly.  The cool things with linked lists is that you can simply move the nodes around in your list, so you would do something like the following:

```
    current = head;
    prev = null;
    while( current != null && current.next != null ){
        next = current.next;

        if( current.iData > next.iData ) {
            // need to swap nodes
        if( prev == null ) {
            // special head case
            head = next;
            current.next = head.next;
            head.next = current;
            }
        else
        {
            prev.next = next;
            current.next = next.next;
            next.next = current;
        }
    }

    // increment pointer
    prev = current;
    current = current.next;
}
```

Comment: Even after modification you have suggested, the loop still remain to spin. Since I think I should shift nodes instead the data.

Comment: Agreed - you should be shifting the nodes; that is the "proper" way of doing it.  However, you seemed to only want to shift data, so I just gave you a quick way to shift data.  I edited the answer to give you an insight on how to shift nodes  (I'm not entirely sure if the logic is 100% correct, but you get the idea).  You have to keep track of the previous node, the current node, and the next node to be able to move the nodes around (ie: previous.next has to point to next, current.next has to point to next.next and next.next has to point to current)